# Can't find image source WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, src

I'm having trouble finding where the purple/blue/pinkish image behind the logo on the front page of academyofperformancearts.com is coming from. Can someone look through the code using inspect element and tell me where it's coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the background image of `<div class="parallax-img parallax-bg-inner">` , and the file is at https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg

Comment: I was having trouble finding the tags in which it was called onto the page, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg

this is the link of the parallaxed image in your website. You can find it in your content upload folder.